# Windows phone 8.1 API for documents?

Tags: c#, api, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to look for an API to fetch files from the documents folder on the Phone. There were no APi's for doing this Windows phone 8.0. Is there anything in windows phone 8.1 ?

Comment: Is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary.aspx) what you're looking for? Scroll down to `DocumentsLibrary`.

Comment: yes, but it reads, 

You can't use the Documents library in a Windows Phone Store app.
You can't publish a Windows Phone Store app that specifies the documentsLibrary capability to the Windows Phone Store. The Store blocks the publishing of the app.
Your app can't access the Documents library in the phone's internal storage. If another app creates a Documents folder on the optional SD card, however, your app can see that folder.

Comment: Sounds conflicting with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh967755.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#accessing_additional_locations) though. The (Windows Store Apps only) part, that is. Confusing. Plus I'm almost positive it's possible with xamarin.

Comment: This link gives information with respect to documents related to OneDrive but not the documents folder itself.

Comment: What kind of windows phone 8.1 app?  Silverlight or universal.

Comment: How does it matter what kinda app i am using? i have tried it on both WRT and Silverlight projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documents library is not accessible programmatically on Windows Phone 8.1. Instead applications are encouraged to use either the [FileOpenPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx) or [FolderPicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx)to allow users to choose files in the documents library.

On Windows applications are able to access the documents library provided they follow the requirements listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary.aspx).

The capabilities are locked down since many users store personal or sensitive information in the documents library, and allowing silent read/write to store applications risks this information leaking. Instead users have complete control (through the pickers) of what files or folders in the documents library apps have access to.